# How to convert userinput date and time and save in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have datetime input textboxes for `StartDate` and `EndDate` by using `<asp:TextBox>` with AjaxToolkit MaskedTextextender. `Enddate` is as same as `StartDate` code.

Here is the code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDateTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1"
    TargetControlID="txtStartDateTime" runat="server" Mask="99/99/9999 99:99"
    MessageValidatorTip="true" MaskType="DateTime"  ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true"
    ClearTextOnInvalid="true" AcceptAMPM="true" UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear"
    ErrorTooltipEnabled="True">
</ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>

<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtStartDateTime" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1"
    IsValidEmpty="false" EmptyValueMessage="Input Date and Time" 
    InvalidValueMessage="Date Time Input Not Valid">
</ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator>
```

Then, I have c# code where I am getting values from those input and save in table at database. Here is my c# code.

```
string strStartDateTime = txtStartDateTime.Text;   
DateTime dtStartingDateTime = new DateTime();    
dtStartingDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strStartDateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now, the problem is I have error when saving those dates to database. This is error message.

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>
> at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format,
>   DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
>
> at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format,
>   IFormatProvider provider)

I tried with `convert.ToDateTime(....)`. It was not working. I am completely lost in how I can save date and time in SQL Server. Can anyone help me how to fix it?

Comment: Whatever you're entering into txtStartDateTime is not matching the exact format you have specified for ParseExact. I don't know anything about the ajaxToolkit, but the "Mask" you have is different than the format. Mask="99/99/9999 99:99" is different than "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"

Comment: Thank. I changed to "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm". But still showing error.

Comment: try to print the strStartDateTime value if having any extra space then trim. Also "99/99/9999 99:99" is not a valid date time. TRy to change the value to "01/01/1999 00:00"

Comment: Well you're pretty much on your own here to get your formats to match. This certainly isn't a sql problem since you're not even getting past parsing input.

Comment: @ray It didn't make any difference. I tried your way. Not working. DateTime format in my html code is Mask="99/99/9999 99:99" wihc is equvalient to "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" in my c# code. Any idea where I went wrong. Thank.

Comment: did you try to see the value of strStartDateTime  in debug mode or put a try catch and try to print the strStartDateTime  value to see wht exactly you are try to parse.

Comment: I use DateTime.Parse(-------); and it is working and saving in database. But I am still not sure how different DateTime.Parse and DateTime.ParseExact ..Thank for helping me all. Joe